# How can Python detect that my RabbitMQ password failed?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I am trying to write a Python application that uses RabbitMQ by means of the [Pika library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pika). I am using the latest version, 0.9.5. My problem is that my Python code cannot detect when its RabbitMQ username and password are incorrect, because I cannot figure out how to register a Pika callback that would inform me of the error. My code is making the connection like this:

```
import pika

class MyClient(object):
    def __init__(self, host, username, password):
        self.host = host
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.connection = None

    def connect(self):
        credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(self.username, self.password)
        parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(
            host=self.host, credentials=credentials, heartbeat=True,
            )
        self.connection = pika.SelectConnection(
            parameters, self.on_connected,
            )
        self.connection.add_on_close_callback(self.on_close)
        self.connection.ioloop.start()

    def on_connected(self, *args, **kw):
        print 'I am connected!', args, kw

    def on_close(self, *args, **kw):
        print 'I am closed!', args, kw

my_client = MyClient('...', '...', '...')
my_client.connect()

# (Good, I remembered to remove the username and password
#  before pasting to Stack Overflow!)
```

If I run this script, then the `ioloop` runs for a bit above three seconds and then the program terminates. I cannot figure out how to register a callback, or even to simply inspect the state of the dead connection, to determine that an error occurred or to find out specifically that it is a bad password error. Have I missed something crucial in the Pika documentation?

Could someone help me understand how Pika 0.9.5 error handling is supposed to work? Or is 0.9.5 some sort of terrible experiment that I should be avoiding by using an earlier version of Pika instead, now that I have noticed [this email message](http://groups.google.com/group/rabbitmq-discuss/browse_thread/thread/405983daa276ea4b?fwc=1) that seems to indicate that this new line of development has become a dead end?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I thought `pika.exceptions.LoginError` is raised if login fails. However, it is only raised if the authentication type provided is not supported by the AMQP broker. It is *not* raised on unsuccessful authentication.

After some hacking around in the Pika source (printing in-bound frames), it seems that after the client sends `Connection.StartOK` (which includes the credentials), if they are not accepted, no response is received. If they *are* accepted, the next frame received is `Connection.Tune`.

I'm not sure what the answer is. Try with the default 'guest:guest' credentials. If they fail, perhaps you have a different problem. Your code snippet works for me with default username:password.

Comment: I am not seeing that exception raised anywhere, so catching it is obviously problematic — it will be great if you find a way for the library to be induced to share the exception with me instead of hiding it away — I am at least glad to know that it exists!

Answer (score 1):

I you want to do AMQP with Python, then you need to have a copy of your library's source code available for searching and browsing. You cannot succeed with these libraries by just using API documentation.

In this case, I am assuming that you don't get a traceback because exceptions are being caught and ignored somewhere. Otherwise you would see the exception that needs to be caught at the bottom of the traceback. Remember, exceptions are objects and some libraries use names like socket.error instead of TypeError or IOError.

You may need to hunt through the code looking for all `except` statements and add a log.debug() call to them.

And if you fix the pika code, make sure to submit a patch.